# What's the point of debuff potions?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

I just found out the crafting recipe for various debuff potions and while that seems like it would be useful to have, I fail to see its use. This is because, while I have plenty of the potions, I can't seem to actually deliver the effects to the enemy. My only option for these potions (that I can see) is to chug them myself, which is far from ideal.

[image: debuff]

**Is there some way to apply the effect to the enemy or is there a possible reason I would want to drink these myself?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about the Enhanced Edition of the game, those debuff potions are a forgotten remnant of when you were able to combine them with grenades and arrows to allow poisoning from afar, back in the classic version of the game. However, the ability to poison arrows and grenades seems to have been removed in the EE version of the game.

Because of this, these potions don't appear to have any real effect anymore.

Answer (score 3):

According to this [wiki page](http://divinityoriginalsin.wiki.fextralife.com/Arrows+Recipes) you can craft arrows  that debuff your enemy in combat with these potions.

For example combining the *Debuff Perception Potion* with an *Arrowhead* results in *Blinding Arrows*.